# How to convert string into int for list of list in python

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

How to convert string into int for list of list in python. My code is below< Because of split my int is converting into string

```
k=int(input())
L = [(input().split()) for _ in range(k)]
L
```

inputs

```
2
11 1
23 4
```

Out

```
[['11', '1'], ['23', '4']]
```

Desired Out

```
[[11, 1], [23, 4]]
```

Comment: Use `map(int, ...)`

Comment: Interesting way of using a list comprehension for an input ! If this turns into actually used code input sanitization however should happen, as the conversion on strings or nothing will fail.

Comment: [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in lst]
or map

>>> [map(int, sublist) for sublist in lst]